# Changing console color, gives me a Stackoverflow Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, console, console-application, console.writeline

I use following methods for printing some text in a different color on console.

```
        private static void WriteUpdatedBookingDetails(string text)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            WriteUpdatedBookingDetails(text);
        }
```

when I execute `WriteUpdatedBookingDetails()` method from following code, it gives me an exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll)

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ...
            // Exception occurred when I call this method. 
            WriteUpdatedBookingDetails("\n- - Reconciling Updated Bookings - -"); 
            ...
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, in debug mode, I get the exception when it calls the method for second time

Comment: But you are invoking `WriteUpdatedBookingDetails()` again and again with the same `text` parameter!

Comment: @GrantWinney: Oh! it was a silly mistake. You are correct.

Comment: @KushanRandima I've edited your post (including code which for normal question would not be good idea, but since this will likely be gone as typographical error it looks like ok to show [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Please consider for future questions to provide *minimal* sample - there really no need to add extra code you had. Also avoid all kind of "thank you"/"new here"/"searched alot" text not relate to your problem. (Feel free to rollback/improve).

Comment: No points for being the first to point out the anomaly! :/
And @GrantWinney why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @HappyCoder Just up voted your answer. Gratitude for spending time on my issue. Thanks

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I understand your points. I will keep it in my mind and follow the instructions in future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you used *recursion*. When you call this method, the foreground is first set to dark green. But as you can see here, you call the same method again! This forms an infinite loop!

When the loop loops for a *lot* of times, your stack overflows. That's why a `StackOverflowException` occurs. I guess you actually want to call

```
Console.WriteLine (text);
```

So this is how your method should look like:

```
private static void WriteUpdatedBookingDetails(string text)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Then, your method will not call itself, so no more recursion!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comment, you are calling `WriteUpdatedBookingDetails()` again-and-again with the same `text` parameter, thus resulting in infinite recursion.

Use `Console.WriteLine()` to print `text` to Console:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Write Updated Booking Details on Console
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        private static void WriteUpdatedBookingDetails(string text)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

in the following function

```
private static void WriteUpdatedBookingDetails(string text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
        WriteUpdatedBookingDetails(text);   //<<<<< here runs the infinite loop
    }
```

you are again calling the same function without any condition. Its running in infinite loop once it's called. That's why you're getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Your calling the WriteUpdatedBookingDetails method from within the WriteUpdatedBookingDetails method.

```
private static void WriteUpdatedBookingDetails(string text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
```